# Why does CORS apply on localhost when using 'lvh.me'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, cross-domain, cors

I was having an issue with CORS in my Rails App and my JS front-end app, before I used rack-cors (https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

The JS front-end app will be a subdomain of my Rails app. So I should not be having this issue in production. However on local, I am running my front-end app on a server with:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

I then access it via `http://dashboard.lvh.me:8000`. All calls are made to the backend rails app to `api.lvh.me:3000`.

When doing requests without handling CORS, I get a CORS error. Why am I getting a CORS error when both are on the same subdomain (lvh.me)? This happened in all browsers.

Why do I need to use rack-cors? Will this also happen in production? Right now, I am just running `rails s`. When using nginx, will this go away when both are on the same domain, but different subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same origin policy applies to the entire domain, even the port number (except in IE).  Sending requests to api.lv.me:3000 from dashboard.lv.me:8000 is a cross-origin request.  In fact, these are also cross-origin calls:

- dashboard.lv.me:8000 -> ap.lv.me:8000
- ap.lv.me:8000 -> ap.lv.me:3000 (except in IE)